# select query multiple tables sql server

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, magento

I am new with sql server. i am trying to compare two tables (items, catalog), between unique code (itemsID) and 3 catalogs IDs (catalogID1, catalogID2, catalogID3). after the comparison, i want to see itemDescription (with the condition/comparison i set).
I wrote the query below, but i can't execute the query with 3 conditions (items.itemsID = catalog.catalogID1 and items.itemsID = catalog.catalogID2 and items.itemsID = catalog.catalogID3), but if i execute each condition by it self (for example, items.itemsID = catalog.catalogID1), it does execute.
How it possible to execute it with all the 3 conditions? Any suggestion will be grateful.

```
select items.itemsDescription
from items, catalog
where items.itemsID = catalog.catalogID1 and items.itemsID = catalog.catalogID2 and items.itemsID = catalog.catalogID3
```

Comment: Could you provide some data samples? I guess you need to join items 3 times but not sure.

Comment: use OR instead of AND?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have incorrect logic. You're saying that `items.itemsID` must be, SIMULTANEOUSLY, three different values. You want an `OR` condition, instead:

```
WHERE items.itemsID = catalog.catalogID1
   OR items.itemsID = catalog.catalogID2
   OR items.itemsID = catalog.catalogID2
```

or more concisely:

```
WHERE items.itemsID IN (catalog.catalogID1, catalog.catalogID2, catalog.catalogID3)
```

Comment: I understand, but the result, showing items.itemsDescription, will consider all 3 conditions?

Comment: So you do want records where all three catalogid values are the SAME value?

Comment: No, all three catalogid are different.

Comment: then you want the `or` version I have above.